# Struts2 getters and setters, intellij says they are not being used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, struts2, getter-setter

In my Struts2  action, the getters and setters are not being used according to IntelliJ IDEA.  Which obviously isn't the case.  They are both greyed out and have the grey squiggly lines underneath them.  Is there anyway to tell IntelliJ IDEA they are being used?

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA, and I did not have this problem with Eclipse.

Comment: Are your getters and setters public?

Comment: I have sometimes the issue, that the annotations stop to work reliable. I'm not sure whether it was with the community edition or with Ultimate, but what you can try is to File->Invalidate Caches and restart IDEA. This of course assumes that your getter/setters are really used.

Comment: Btw, it would be helpful if you would specify your system completely: operating system, IDEA version.

Comment: Mac osx 10.9.1, IDEA 13.0.1.  The struts getters and setters are never explicitly called by me.  It's all handled by struts.  Which I think is where IDEA is having the issue.

Comment: @halirutan Invalidate caches and restart did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA marks grey unused methods or fields if they are not used in the code. You could check that with highlighting a word and press <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd>. If you do this with grey word it will show a message that *"No usages found"*. This means that usages in your code, it doesn't include a reflection API code. IntelliJ IDEA use inspections to highlight elements of the code if it doesn't comply the rules defined in the inspection profile which you can configure if you click on the man icon in the status bar. Also, there you can choose a highlighting level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm confused on where I set the highlighting level.  I've looked in properties-->inspections, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Do you see a man icon on the status bar? Click on it then choose "Configure inspections" in the popup window.

Comment: Thanks!  I wish there was a better way, as I would generally like to know if I am not using something, but I will mark this as correct.  Thanks again!!

Comment: http://www.struts2.info/blog/identifying-struts2-setters-with-a-custom-annotation

Comment: @StevenBenitez Cool, but how much it differs from `@SuppressWarning("unused")`?

Comment: @RomanC It conveys its meaning more accurately, serving as documentation that indicates that the annotated field is mapped to a request parameter that will be set via reflection rather than just saying "suppress this warning." Otherwise, they are functionally identical.

Comment: @StevenBenitez Then it should have an opposite effect if the field is not affected by reflection if the annotation is applied on it there should be a warning, so it leads to write your own compiler. That's out of the topic here. Thanks for comments.

Comment: @RomanC Huh? It's just a source annotation. It's discarded during compilation just like a comment is, but its more uniform than a comment and suppresses the unused warning within IntelliJ.